# Is it natural to use the phrase "who are you to do something" when expressing anger?

Tags: phrases

Is it natural to say the following when expressing anger at someone for something they have done, and they don't have the right to do the thing?

> Who are you to behave like that?!
>
> Who are you to teach me how to talk to people?!

Comment: It's completely natural in British English.

Comment: And American English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Who are you to [do something]?" is common in English, and is used to mean "what right do you have to [do something]?", in a situation where the speaker thinks that the listener does not have any such right. "Who are you to tell me what to wear? You're not my parent!" "Who are you to call me a drunkard? You like a drop yourself; everybody knows that!".

> Nay but, O man, who art thou that repliest against God? Shall the
>   thing formed say to him that formed it, Why hast thou made me thus?
>
> *or if you prefer:*
>
> But who are you, a human being, to talk back to God? "Shall what is
>   formed say to the one who formed it, 'Why did you make me like this?'"

[Romans 9:20](https://biblehub.com/romans/9-20.htm)

> Who are you, to point your finger at me
>   Who are you, to tell me I ain't no good
>   Who are you, who are you
>   Who are you, who are you

[Who Are You? (Mr Probz)](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/mrprobz/whoareyou.html)

> Who are you to question my wisdom with your ignorant, empty words?

[Job 38:2](https://www.biblestudytools.com/gnta/job/passage/?q=job%2038:2-12)

> According to the Telegraph, Lavrov berated his boyish British
>   counterpart, asking at one point, “Who are you to f—— lecture me?” The
>   Daily Mail has it as “Who the f— are you to lecture me?” and quotes a
>   Whitehall source saying, “It was effing this and effing that. It was
>   not what you would call diplomatic language. It was rather shocking.”

[Russian Minister](https://foreignpolicy.com/2008/09/17/russian-minister-who-are-you-to-f-lecture-me/)

> Who Are You To Ask Me Who I Am? Two Party Authentication Is A Must

[ITSP Magazine](https://www.itspmagazine.com/from-the-newsroom/who-are-you-to-ask-me-who-i-am-two-party-authentication-is-a-must)

> Who are you to tell us what to do? Last week, I came across an article titled "Ladies, Please Stop Doing This On Instagram".

[The Odysseyonline](https://www.theodysseyonline.com/response-to-ladies-please-stop-doing-this-on-instagram)

> Who Are You to Judge ME?

[HuffPost](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/who-are-you-to-judge-me_b_1850841)

Comment: I can only comment from my own experience as someone living in Britain that the phrase "Who are you to [do something]?" to me is something that comes off as awkward, if I heard someone say this in the wild I would have to complete a double-take. To clarify, the reason this is so awkward is because of how formal it is. If you were yo say something like this, it wouldn't naturally be said so formally.

Comment: I hear it lots, and it is generally said informally. In particular, expressions like "who are you to [say something] to me?"

Comment: Perhaps we just live in different parts of the UK but I do agree that it makes sense, just weird to myself.

Comment: Bristol, born in London, 67 years old.

Comment: Edinburgh, not as old, defo different regions :)

Comment: I repeat, very common in UK English. Looks like American too. Despite the downvote.

Comment: Native AmE: Here, it's pretty common and ordinary. I found it mystifying when I first heard it as a little kid, but eventually I understood it when I understood how it expresses perception in relation to a dominance hierarchy. +1 for great range of examples as well as correct explanation.

Comment: I got stung into adding the examples to my answer just now, because someone downvoted.